# Symbol Entities as glyphicon

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, fonts, font-awesome, glyphicons

Can someone tell me, is there a chance that I can find this Symbol `&diams;` as `bootstrap glyphicon` I need to style a `li` object.

I know I can use it like this

```
        <ul class="list-unstyled">
            <li>&diams; Some text here</li>
            <li>&diams; Some text here</li>
            <li>&diams; Some text here</li>
            <li>&diams; Some text here.</li>
            <li>&diams; Some text here </li>
        </ul>
```

and I will have diamonds, but is there a `glypicon`, I looked bootstrap 3 `glyphicon` and `fontawesome` icon's but I didn't found it, so is there an icon for `diamonds` or not.

Comment: icomoon has a diamond... https://icomoon.io/#preview-free

Comment: Thanks, busted mine keyboard google in around.

Comment: I found it at http://glyphsearch.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IcoMoon has a diamond icon in the free set.

https://icomoon.io/#preview-free

`<i class="icomoon icon-diamonds"></i>`